# Issue with context Click in webdriverjs

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried to context click on an element using:

```
const action=await page.driver.actions({bridge: true});
await action.contextClick(element,webdriver.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

But the action is not seen to happen. Instead it opens me a new browser window in chrome. Is there a way to deal with issue. Please help?

Also please help me if there is any sources that could help into looking the webdriverjs API docs.